# How to verify events fired when a button is clicked using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium suite that runs on our user interactive website. Our company also tracks the event that are fired when a user interact with an input field (such a numeric input or slider) on third party such as google analytics. I am trying to verify the events fired when a user clicks on a button on a page. Is there a way, selenium can track that event in console and verify it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches that you could take in order to achieve what you're looking for:

1. Parse WebDriver's logs and get required info from there, here is an example on how to get them from chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log - please note that for, for example, firefox - capabilities would be different, also you won't be able to get response codes and response time, only basic info.
2. Create proxy, configure wd to use it and capture traffic using proxy, one of the solutions is called [BrowserMob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). Once traffic goes through you may get Har file from proxy and get all the data from there. Har captures all the data you may need: request, params, response code, response timings.